# Javascript SQLite: SELECT statement with WHERE IN clause

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

In `Javascript` `SQLite`, is there a better way we can execute a `SELECT` statement with `WHERE IN` clause? Let's take the following query as an example:

```
var ids = [1, 5, 10];

function getBranches (ids) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Branch WHERE id in ?', [ids], function(tx,results){

            // process results
        });

    });
}
```

I know we can always format the `WHERE IN` clause for the ids in a way `SQL` recognizes it as shown below. But I was wondering if there's a nice way to achieve that requirement.

```
function getBranches (ids) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {

            var idClause = ' id in (\"' + ids.join("\",\"") + '\");';

            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Branch WHERE ' + idClause, [], function(tx,results){

                // process results
            });

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

One way is to do without the placeholder `?`:

```
'SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 in (' + ids.join(',') + ')', [],...
```

**Solution 2:**

Another way is to do the fancy prepared statement style as in your example, where you need to put exact number of `?` that equals the number of arguments.

```
var ids = [1, 5, 10];

var placeHolders = new Array(ids.length).fill('?').join(',');

var query = 'SELECT * FROM Branch WHERE id in ('+ placeHolders + ')';

tx.executeSql(query, [ids], ...
```